# Oracle DataGuard between 11.2.0.4 (primary) and 19c (physical standby)

Tags: oracle, backup, high-availability

Our production database is on 11.2.0.4. It needs to be upgraded to 19c.

Can I setup physical standby which is at 19c and keep it in sync with primary ?

Thereafter - during a weekend maintenance, the standby database will be designated switched over to 19c.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 11.2.0.4 physical standby, which can be converted to a logical standby, which can be upgraded to 19c after which you can keep that in sync with the 11.2.0.4 primary until the switchover.

Comment: Let me ask question differently - can a 11.2.0.4 database have a 19c version as standby ?

Comment: @oradbanj That is the same question, and the answer is also the same, as above.